# Going to next frame and then removing movieClip in it after a few seconds (Actionscript 2)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm working on a shooting game. This is my case, how can I make my enemy going to next frame wich is contain impact movieclip when its being shoot by player and then remove the movieclip it self

***It's just like when you shoot a car, and then explode and then the explode disappear after few second***

here is my code in frame:

```js
stop(); //add a stop function too!

var gameOver: Boolean = false;

var mainSpeed: Number = 10; //how fast the main guy can move

//BULLET TIMING VARIABLES
var cTime: Number = 0; //the amount of frames that has elapsed since last bullet shot
var cLimit: Number = 12; //amount of frames needed to shoot another bullet
var shootAllow: Boolean = false; //whether or not main can shoot
//ENEMY TIMING VARIABLES
//how much time before another enemy is made
var enemyTime: Number = 0;
//how much time needed to make an enemy
//it should be more than the shooting rate
//or else killing all of the enemies would
//be impossible :O
var enemyLimit: Number = 50;
//showing the amount of enemies that have been added to the stage
var enemyTotal: Number = 0;

//the player's score
var score: Number = 0;

//this movieclip will hold all of the bullets
_root.createEmptyMovieClip('bulletHolder', _root.getNextHighestDepth());

onEnterFrame = function() { //this function will run every frame (needed for moving the character
  if (Key.isDown(37) || Key.isDown(65)) { //if the "A" key or Left Arrow Key is Down
    bat._x -= mainSpeed; //then the move the guy left
  }
  if (Key.isDown(38) || Key.isDown(87)) { //if the "W" key or Up Arrow Key is Down
    bat._y -= mainSpeed; //then move the guy up
  }
  if (Key.isDown(39) || Key.isDown(68)) { //if the "D" key or Right Arrow Key is Down
    bat._x += mainSpeed; //then move the guy to the right
  }
  if (Key.isDown(40) || Key.isDown(83)) { //if the "S" key or Down Arrow Key is Down
    bat._y += mainSpeed; //then move the guy down
  }

  //keeping the main character within bounds
  if (bat._x <= 0) {
    bat._x += mainSpeed;
  }
  if (bat._y <= 0) {
    bat._y += mainSpeed;
  }
  if (bat._x >= 500) {
    bat._x -= mainSpeed;
  }
  if (bat._y >= 500) {
    bat._y -= mainSpeed;
  }

  if (Key.isDown(32) && shootAllow) { //if the space bar is pressed
    var bulletID: Number = Math.random(); //create a variable that we'll use at the bullet's id
    //then attach a bullet to the stage
    bulletHolder.attachMovie('fire', 'Bullet' + bulletID, _root.getNextHighestDepth());
    //setting the coordinates of the bullet to be the same as the main character
    bulletHolder['Bullet' + bulletID]._x = bat._x;
    bulletHolder['Bullet' + bulletID]._y = bat._y - 70;
    bulletHolder['Bullet' + bulletID].onEnterFrame = function() {
      //giving the bullet some actions
      this._y -= 50; //moving the bullet
      if (this._y < -1 * this._height) { //if the bullet goes off stage
        //then destroy it
        this.removeMovieClip();
      }

      //checking if the game is over
      if (gameOver) {
        //destroy this guy if the game is over
        this.removeMovieClip();
      }
    }
    shootAllow = false;
  }

  cTime++; //increment the time
  if (cTime == cLimit) { //if enough time has elapsed
    shootAllow = true; //allow shooting again
    cTime = 0; //reset the time
  }

  enemyTime++; //incrementing time for enemy
  if (enemyTime == enemyLimit) { //if enough time has elapsed
    _root.attachMovie('thug', 'en' + enemyTotal, _root.getNextHighestDepth()); //then add the enemy
    //setting it's coordinates
    _root['en' + enemyTotal]._x = int(Math.random() * Stage.width); //randomly within the boundaries
    _root['en' + enemyTotal]._y = -50; //sets this offstage at first
    _root['en' + enemyTotal].onEnterFrame = function() { //then give it some functions
      this._y += 5;

      //run a loop checking if it's touching any bullets
      for (var cBullet: String in _root.bulletHolder) {
        //if it's touching the bullet
        //we have to use coordinates because hit testing doesn't seem to work
        if (this._y >= _root.bulletHolder[cBullet]._y - 50 && this._y <= _root.bulletHolder[cBullet]._y) {
          if (this._x <= _root.bulletHolder[cBullet]._x + 25 && this._x >= _root.bulletHolder[cBullet]._x - 55) {
            //then destroy this guy
            //this is where I tried to make it work but
            //it just change the movieclip but not removed it
            this.gotoAndStop(2)
            if (_root.thug.frame = 2) {
              _root.thug.removeMovieClip();
            }
            //and destroy the bullet
            _root.bulletHolder[cBullet].removeMovieClip();

            //up the score
            _root.score += 5;
          }
        }
      }

      //hit testing with the user
      if (this.hitTest(_root.bat)) {
        //set the game to be over and go to lose screen
        gameOver = true;
        gotoAndStop(2);
      }

      //checking if the game is over
      if (gameOver) {
        //destroy this guy if the game is over
        this.removeMovieClip();
      }
    }
    enemyTime = 0; //reset the time
    enemyTotal++; //add 1 more to the amount of enemies total
  }

  //updating the score text field
  txtScore.text = 'Score:  ' + score;
}
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Just make another function that would remove your movieclip and call it with a delay:

```
setTimeout(onTimeout, 2000); // call the onTimeout function with a delay of 2 seconds

function onTimeout()
{
    this.removeMovieClip();
}
```

I'm just not sure if you will be able to call this new function out of your main function because it was declared in the onEnterFrame scope. So if that doesn't work you might need to modify your main function a bit:

```
onEnterFrame = onEnterFrameFunction;

function onEnterFrameFunction()
{
    // move your onEnterFrame code here
}
```